# How to write a query to display the mobiles whose manufacturing date is specified as 2010?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

[image: 1]]

Based on this table, i wrote a query to display mobiles whose date of manufacturing is before 2010.

```
SELECT
  ime_no,
  model_name,
  manufacturer,
  date_of_manufac
FROM mobileinfo
WHERE date_of_manufac < 2010;
```

but, error occurred

ERROR at line 3:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

help me in solving this error and the query to display mobiles whose date of manufacturing is before 2010!!!

Comment: Maybe if you actually gave it a date, like `'2010-1-1'` it would be happy? Also is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen . . . ORA errors come from Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know. Just trying to help the asker realize there shouldn't be improper tags in the question.

Comment: Oh...  The MySQL answer is **Correct**, for a problem where the code is in Oracle, not MySQL? How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ime_no,model_name,manufacturer,date_of_manufac
from mobileinfo
where STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date_of_manufac,%Y),%Y)<2010;
```

Here I had added function[**`DATE_FORMAT`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) and [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php).

Try above query.

Comment: The OP uses Oracle (perhaps the tags weren't right initially, but the error message ORA-... is clear).

Answer (score 2):

One method is to extract the year from the date:

```
where extract(year from date_of_manufac) < 2010;
```

More generally, just use date comparisons:

```
where date_of_manufac < date '2010-01-01'
```

This is preferable, because it can make use of an index on the column -- if one is available and the use of the index is appropriate for the query.

Comment: Given OP's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, your second query will not work with a ORA-01843: not a valid month. Either use '01-JAN-10' or force the date conversion < TO_DATE('01-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: @LauDec . . . "To specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:  `DATE '1998-12-25'`".

Comment: You are totally right. I missed the DATE keyword before the literal. thanks for the clarification. My comment only applies if you omit the DATE